# Export csv file from server with POST request

Tags: angularjs

I know how to get csv from back-end with GET request (via $window.location).

But is there a way to do this, if i want to send POST request? I've tried to do it with $http.post, but as i understood, it is impossible to transfer data with xhr query, but i'm not sure

Comment: That's an interesting question! Unless you can configure the server to send the CSV in response to a POST request, no, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Not a problem if you submit a form to server side script. What are you trying to do with csv...provide as a download from server?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin of course it's possible and it is done all the time

Comment: @charlietfl I'm an idiot.